# Select data based on data in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
|id| username     |
-------------------
|1 |John Doe      |
|2 |Jane Doe      |
|3 |Luke Skywalker|

|id|user_id|group_id|
---------------------
|1 |1      |5       |
|2 |1      |6       |
|3 |2      |6       |
```

I am trying to filter out users already in a group so the same user can not be added twice to the same group.

How can I select let's say all users from table1 who are not in group_id = 5 in table2?

Comment: Did you find your answer in the replies below?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.*
FROM table1 u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2 g
    WHERE g.user_id = u.id AND g.group_id = 5
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM table2 WHERE group_id=5)
```

But, to ensure uniqueness, you'd better add a UNIQUE KEY on `(user_id, group_id)` in table2:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD UNIQUE KEY unique_user_group (user_id, group_id);
```

this way, MySQL itself won't accept duplicate records, without worring to check each time on the application side.

Comment: The IN is usually slower than the EXISTS. EXISTS stops if it founds one record, while the subquery in the IN clause, always select all the records

Comment: IN is more elegant and performance probably isn't much concern to him/her

Comment: Good point, but isn't the subquery run only once, instead of for each record, when using `IN`?

Comment: Correct. But if the subquery returns a large set of data, it will affect the performance

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use a join clause with a <> in the where clause.  Assuming they are joined on user_id this should work.

This will give you results from both tables without the ones in table 2 that are = 5.

```
SELECT  *
  FROM   table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.id
   WHERE   t2.group_id <> 5
```